# Disparador con llaves foráneas

Tags: mysql

Quiero crear un disparador para actualizar la cantidad de productos de mi tabla: Productos cuando se hace una inserción en la tabla Aparece. Ya que en la tabla Aparece manejo la cantidad de productos que se compran y las quiero descontar a mis productos para tener la cantidad total disponible.

Mi línea en MySQL y Apache es la siguiente:

Mi tabla Aparece:

```
CREATE TABLE Aparece -- ( -- Folio_P CHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
-- Codigo_producto VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL, 
-- precio INT NOT NULL, 
-- cantidad INT NOT NULL, 
-- CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY ( Folio_P) 
REFERENCES -- pedidos(Folio_P), -- CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY ( codigo_producto) references -- productos(codigo_producto) -- )
```

Mi tabla: Producto

```
CREATE TABLE Productos -- ( -- codigo_producto VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY, 
-- Marca VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
-- precio INT NOT NULL, -- Existencia INT NOT NULL -- )
```

Comment: Hola, dónde vas a actualizar la cantidad de productos? La pregunta no se entiende bien.

Comment: Los productos los quiero actualizar de la tabla productos

Comment: Y qué problema tuviste creando el disparador?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el problema que tenes?

Comment: Mi problema es que no encuentra la columna pregunta